# A priori argument fallacy

Tags: logic, fallacies, propositional-logic

Considering the "A priori argument logical fallacy" (see https://utminers.utep.edu/omwilliamson/engl1311/fallacies.htm)

Is there a way to formalize it (technical expression) using the notation of propositional logic?

Thanks for your help

Comment: No, there isn't. It is not a formal fallacy, so there is no way to express it formally. If I understand the description of it correctly, it appears to be a kind of epistemic fallacy, akin to begging the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior described is *motivated reasoning* (see: wikipedia: [Motivated Reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motivated_reasoning)). It isn't a logical fallacy, it's a cognitive bias which can, but does not always, lead to cognitive error.

The name isn't ideal:  since reasoning is a conscious act, and conscious acts have motives, all reasoning, including error-free reasoning, is "motivated" when you get down to it. We could rename it more usefully to something like "emotion-dictated information screening bias".

The error attendant to the bias is in how you seek, sort, and use available information. The information includes the data that may constitute implicit or explicit premises in your argument, which may render conclusions indefensible despite arguments being logically sound by the presence of incomplete or irrelevant data in the premises. Or the premises themselves may be false conclusions of the really available data: for instance, the data may be "X organization says Y", but it may appear in a premise as "Y is true". The information also includes meta-information about your own reasoning, making it hard for you to notice if you are making fallacious arguments.

You cannot rid yourself of cognitive biases, and it's not clear at all that you should even want to. Your job as a rational thinker is to work to reduce the rate at which your biases turn into errors by developing habits and orientations of thought which bias you towards seeking truth.

Keep in mind that although the available evidence shouldn't be constrained by your emotions and intuitions, your emotions and intuitions are themselves a vital part of the available evidence.

Answer (score 1):

The fallacy as described at the link is not a fallacy. He's essentially saying that if you have a pre-existing belief in something and then try to develop an argument for it based on other premises, that this is a fallacy. This is not only not a fallacy, it is how most arguments are probably developed.

Much of what people believe they believe for pre-rational reasons. The essence of rational argumentation is to find a better, more solid grounds for what you already believe, or at least more universal, more persuasive grounds. Euclid already believed that the base of a triangle was shorter than the sum of the two sides before he proved the theorem. Archimedes already believed the law of the lever before he proved it. Thomas Jefferson already believed that he was justified in rebelling against England before he wrote the Declaration of Independence. Descartes already believed that he existed before he wrote his argument that he existed.

Arguing for your existing pre-rational beliefs is not only not a fallacy, it is a valuable intellectual exercise.

Comment: You make a good point. But surely, there is such a thing as begging the question, and if you make your pre-rational belief an axiom of your argument, you put it beyond refutation and not in need of justification. The link in the question suggests "since we know there is no such thing as 'evolution,' a prime duty of believers is to look for ways to explain away growing evidence, such as is found in DNA, that might suggest otherwise."

Comment: @LudwigV, if you assume that P is true while proving P, that is begging the question. If you believe that P is true and this is your motivation for arguing that P, then this is just normal intellectual discussion. The example you cite is neither. The person giving the example is committing the fallacy of argumentum ad hominem. Rather than addressing the other person's argument, he is attacking their motives.

Comment: Yes. You are taking the example in the text in a way I hadn't thought of, and I think the author had not taken into account. I think the argument is intended to be taken as addressed to other believers. On reflection, it would then count as an exhortation and hence not really an argument. The interesting point is that "If you believe that P is true and this is your motivation for arguing that P" introduces the question of motivation and context.

Comment: Which I take to show that argumentation is not captured by purely formal considerations. The motivation of seeking the truth means that when I argue for something I believe in, I must put my belief at stake in the argument. Otherwise, it is doesn't count as an argument, but rather as persuasion, which is a misuse, or at least different use, of the formal arguments. (Roughly).